# parsing almost well formed XML fragments: how to skip over multiple XML headers

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.0, xml-parsing, xmlreader

I’m required to write a tool that can handle the below XML fragment that is not well formed as it contains XML declarations in the middle of the stream.

The company already has these kinds files in use for a long time, so there is no option to change the format.

There is no source code available that does the parsing, and the platform of choice for new tooling is .NET 4 or newer preferably with C#.

This is how the fragments look like:

```
<Header>
  <Version>1</Version>
</Header>
<Entry><?xml version="1.0"?><Detail>...snip...</Detail></Entry>
<Entry><?xml version="1.0"?><Detail>...snip...</Detail></Entry>
<Entry><?xml version="1.0"?><Detail>...snip...</Detail></Entry>
<Entry><?xml version="1.0"?><Detail>...snip...</Detail></Entry>
```

Using an [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8a5e1s5) with the [XmlReaderSettings.ConformanceLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.conformancelevel.aspx) set to [ConformanceLevel.Fragment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2344bs2.aspx), I can read the complete `<Header>` element fine.
Even the `<Entry>` element start is OK, however while reading the `<Detail>` info the `XmlReader` it throws an [XmlException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlexception.aspx), as it reads in the `<?xml...?>` XML declaration which it doesn't expect at that place.

What options do I have to skip over those XML declarations, besides heavy string manipulations?

Since the fragments can easily go above 100 megabyte a piece, I'd rather do not load everything into memory at once.  But it that is what it takes, I am open for it.

Example of the exceptions I get:

```
System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected XML declaration.
The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it.
Line ##, position ##.
```

Comment: Do you tried using classes from the System.Xml.Linq (http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb299195) namespace?

Comment: not yet; which ones are best to start with for parsing fragments? How memory hungry is LINQ? These files can easily be 100 megabyte a piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the built in classes will help; you'll probably have to do some preparsing and remove the extra  headers.  If your sample is accurate, you can just do a `string.Replace(badXml, "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>, "")` and be on your way.

Comment: Thanks. That's similar to what I've used until now, but I'm not sure the XML declarations stays that constant. It is good to read that we're thinking along the same line.

Comment: I couldn't accept both answers, and added my own code as a separate answer answer so syntax highlighting is preserved. Your answer is accepted as it is closest to what I already had.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure that the declarations stay the same all the time, replace `<?xml` with `<XmlDeclaration` and `?>` with `/>` and use a regular parser ;)

Also, have you tried passing the files through an XML tidy style program?

There might also be an SGML library you can use to preprocess the data and output correct XML.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I know I can do RegEx, and will when no better alternatives can be found. XMLTidy from TextPad chokes because the files are too large. Any pointers to such an SGML library would be appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't accept both answers, and added my own code as a separate answer answer so syntax highlighting is preserved. Your answer is not accepted as it is further from what I already had. Sorry (:

Answer (score 0):

I added this as an answer because it preserves syntax highlighting.

```
    private void ProcessFile(string inputFileName, string outputFileName)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputFileName, new UTF8Encoding(false, true)))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputFileName, false, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    const string xmlDeclarationStart = "<?xml";
                    const string xmlDeclarationFinish = "?>";
                    if (line.Contains(xmlDeclarationStart))
                    {
                        string newLine = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf(xmlDeclarationStart));
                        int endPosition = line.IndexOf(xmlDeclarationFinish, line.IndexOf(xmlDeclarationStart));
                        if (endPosition == -1)
                        {
                            throw new NotImplementedException(string.Format("Implementation assumption is wrong. {0} .. {1} spans multiple lines (or input file is severely misformed)", xmlDeclarationStart, xmlDeclarationFinish));
                        }
                        // the code completely strips the <?xml ... ?> part
                        // an alternative would be to make this a new XML element containing
                        // the information inside the <?xml ... ?> part as attributes
                        // just like Daren Thomas suggested
                        newLine += line.Substring(endPosition + 2);
                        line = newLine;
                    }
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```